# Can you force a SaveFileDialog to have light/dark mode

Tags: c#, winforms

By default the `SaveFileDialog` and other Dialog windows are colored depending on the system settings. Is there a way to force it to be light/dark mode?

I tried using the `AutoUpgradeEnabled` property but that comes at the cost of functionality + it only works for light mode.